# Windows Messagebox Icons in VS2008 using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am looking for the Icon's that are standard on the Messagebox control. I want to use these Icon's on my Form. Where are they located at and the names of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to use an icon, you can use an image control and set the image from System.Drawing.SystemIcons.  Many standard icons are available.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the icons can be found at [VS2008 home directory]\Common7\VS2008ImageLibrary\VS2008ImageLibrary.zip